# Avg Value. vs CPA value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if someone could help me to wrap my head around the avg. formula and CPA formula.

Avg. Value between the two shows as 219.34, which is correct for an average value. However, Account 1 CPA and Account 2 CPA have been calculated from the same formula, so I guess that the Avg. Total value should match the formula as well, but it doesn't!

[image: Excel issue]

Answer (score 0):

[image: See this Image]

I have Solved your Problem Please see Attached Image I have used *=CPC/CR%* and It is returning $111.43

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve the issue, I don't understand how come my CPA value is different from the Avg. value even though I have used the same formula for first 2